# Youtube Video Insert returns "default" video resource

Tags: python-2.7, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to upload a video from an S3 bucket to YouTube, and getting back strange output that implies a successful post, but doesn't give anything expected back. As well, I set attributes like `title` and `description` in my code, but as you can see from the output, this isn't actually being set.

**Example Output:**

```
{
  "id": "-pfZ_BNH9kg",
  "snippet": {
    "channelId": "UCZ5AUe-rp3rXKeFS0yx4ZBA",
    "title": "unknown",
    "channelTitle": "Patrick Hanford",
    "publishedAt": "2020-04-30T19:22:15.000Z",
    "thumbnails": {
      "high": {
        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/-pfZ_BNH9kg/hqdefault.jpg",
        "height": 360,
        "width": 480
      },
      "default": {
        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/-pfZ_BNH9kg/default.jpg",
        "height": 90,
        "width": 120
      },
      "medium": {
        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/-pfZ_BNH9kg/mqdefault.jpg",
        "height": 180,
        "width": 320
      }
    },
    "localized": {
      "title": "unknown",
      "description": ""
    },
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
    "categoryId": "20",
    "description": ""
  },
  "etag": "Dn5xIderbhAnUk5TAW0qkFFir0M/3T1YGvGo1YyaTKtTpl8JrJqWS4M",
  "status": {
    "embeddable": true,
    "privacyStatus": "public",
    "uploadStatus": "uploaded",
    "publicStatsViewable": true,
    "license": "youtube"
  },
  "kind": "youtube#video"
}
```

**Upload Code:**

```py
    def post(self, attempts=None):
        TEST_VIDEO = "http://streamon-perm.s3.amazonaws.com/WPHM-48k-pl-33366.mp4"

        headers = {"Content-Type": "video/mp4"}

        upload_request_body = {
            "snippet": {
                "title": "Test Video Upload",
                "description": "This is a test of uploading videos.",
                "categoryId": "22",
            },
            "status": {
                "privacyStatus": "public"
            },
            "fileDetails": {
                "fileName": TEST_VIDEO,
                "fileType": "video"
            }
        }

        params = {
            "access_token": self.google_token.get("access_token", None),
            "id": self.google_token.get("id_token", None),
            "part": "snippet, status"
        }

        extra = {
            "client_id": self.client_id,
            "client_secret": self.client_secret
        }

        google_oauth_session = OAuth2Session(
            self.client_id,
            token=self.google_token,
            auto_refresh_url=self.token_url,
            auto_refresh_kwargs=extra,
            token_updater=self._save_token
        )

        upload_response = google_oauth_session.post(
            self.video_post_url,
            headers=headers,
            json=upload_request_body,
            params=params
        )
        logger.info("Response from VIDEO UPLOAD: %s", repr(upload_response.content))
        return True
```

I have also tried downloading the file from S3 and uploading with the file directly, and I get the same result. Without proper error messages or anything to go off of, I'm really not sure what to try next. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have also tried using `requests` by itself rather than using `oauthlib` with exactly the same result.

```py
    def post(self, attempts=None):
        if attempts is None:
            attempts = 0
        if self.neutered:
            msg = "Youtube post() disabled by ENVIRONMENT variables."
            logger.info(msg)
            return msg
        logger.info("Youtube post() entered with attempt # %s", self.post_attempts)

        if self.google_token is None:
            self.google_token = self._set_google_token()
            attempts += 1
            self.post(attempts=attempts)

        headers = {
            "Content-Type": "video/mp4",
            "client_id": self.client_id,
            "client_secret": self.client_secret,
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + self.google_token["access_token"]
            }

        params = {
            "access_token": self.google_token.get("access_token", None),
            "id": self.google_token.get("id_token", None),
            "part": "snippet, status"
        }

        upload_request_body = {
            "snippet": {
                "title": "Test Video Upload",
                "description": "This is a test of uploading videos from POST.",
                "categoryId": "22",
            },
            "status": {
                "privacyStatus": "public"
            },
            "fileDetails": {
                "fileName": TEST_VIDEO,
                "fileType": "video"
            }
        }

        upload_response = requests.post(
            self.video_post_url,
            params=params,
            headers=headers,
            json=upload_request_body
        )
        logger.info("Response from VIDEO UPLOAD: %s", repr(upload_response.content))
        return True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have also tried downloading the file from S3 and uploading with the file directly, and I get the same result.

Your have this issue probably due to the fact that you are not actually sending the file. `upload_request_body.fileDetails.fileName` is not the place for the link/file. It's just a description attribute.

Have you tried an auto-generated code from https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/code_snippets ?
This is what you can get there:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Sample Python code for youtube.videos.insert
# NOTES:
# 1. This sample code uploads a file and can't be executed via this interface.
#    To test this code, you must run it locally using your own API credentials.
#    See: https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/guides/code_samples#python
# 2. This example makes a simple upload request. We recommend that you consider
#    using resumable uploads instead, particularly if you are transferring large
#    files or there's a high likelihood of a network interruption or other
#    transmission failure. To learn more about resumable uploads, see:
#    https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/media_upload

import os

import googleapiclient.discovery

from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

def main():
    # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
    # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    DEVELOPER_KEY = "YOUR_API_KEY"

    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, developerKey = DEVELOPER_KEY)

    request = youtube.videos().insert(
        part="snippet,status",
        body={
          "fileDetails": {
            "fileName": "qwer",
            "fileType": "video"
          },
          "snippet": {
            "categoryId": "22",
            "description": "This is a test of uploading videos.",
            "title": "Test Video Upload"
          },
          "status": {
            "privacyStatus": "public"
          }
        },

        # TODO: For this request to work, you must replace "YOUR_FILE"
        #       with a pointer to the actual file you are uploading.
        media_body=MediaFileUpload("YOUR_FILE")
    )
    response = request.execute()

    print(response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I believe it should work.

<sup>Or is there any reason not to use `googleapiclient`?</sup>

---

> I'm trying to upload a video from an S3 bucket to YouTube

I doubt that you can upload files from other sites directly to *Youtube*. Probably you are stuck with the option of uploading files from your own server/drive. I've looked up on the Internet but all I've found is that you can't (although you could in the past). And one can imagine a lot of reasons why this is not allowed (mostly copyright but not exclusively).

### Update:

Probably, that was not an exhaustive code snippet. Especially, considering that you need *OAuth2*.

But here is another one:
https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/upload_video.py

And yet another:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video

With *OAuth2*. There you can also find information on `client_secrets.json`.

> ```
> {
>  "web": {
>    "client_id": "[[INSERT CLIENT ID HERE]]",
>    "client_secret": "[[INSERT CLIENT SECRET HERE]]",
>    "redirect_uris": [],
>    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
>    "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"
>  }
> }
> ```

Also you can checkout some real life projects. For example this one: https://github.com/HA6Bots/Automatic-Youtube-Reddit-Text-To-Speech-Video-Generator-and-Uploader/tree/master/Youtube%20Bot%20Video%20Generator

Comment: I've seen this example, but its super ambiguous. How would this upload a video on a user's behalf when there's nowhere to pass an access_token for instance? Maybe this is possible, but why is it not documented when that's arguably the most common/only use case. What channel would this video even go to?

Comment: I suppose it comes from the `-oauth.json` file, but now what does that file look like? What if I don't want to create a JSON file every time. I just don't understand and wish they'd just document the client instead of giving a very specific example. Are you able to answer these questions for sake of achieving the expected result?

Comment: @CodeSpent, yea, *Google* is not so great with good and simple docs. Updated the answer with examples more relevant to you case.

Comment: Appreciate it, but not quite fitting to my case. I'll still accept this answer since it does answer the overall question, but I did find that what I need to do is use the googleoauthlib to first generate a Credentials object with the access_token I had stored to pass to the client. Couldn't find it in docs, had to go diving into the client code for hours which is a bit disappointing.

Comment: The biggest issue is as you illustrate here as well. It's very common to find "how to perform an upload" and "how to use oauth", but what's missing is the bridge between those; "how do you use a user's authorization credentials to upload a video". Your update misses that point as well, which isn't a jab at you, but a jab at the overall design. It really shouldn't be an ordeal, just keep it simple, Google.

Comment: Do you mean this https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/master/docs/auth.md ? And more specifically this https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/master/docs/client-secrets.md and this https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#creatingcred ?

Comment: Yes. It does explain how a user authenticated request is made, even in examples of user authenticated requests. The docs exist, sure, but as I said, they only talk about 1 or the other. There's no mention of creating a Credentials object from the user's access_token. What you've linked is for application credentials (client id & secret). As far as I can tell, there's no clear documentation on this process anywhere except the autogenerated docs which fail to mention the ability to pass a Credentials object from the googleoauthlib to the google-api-client.